# Remove droppable element with Angularjs Drag&Drop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shitsu/jncbu7s2/) using the Angular [Drag and Drop](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#) module.
What I want: on the left, a list of cards. Each of them is draggable. On the right, a drop area. Upon drag-drop, the element is cloned and added to the `ctrl.program` list. So far, so good.

**The problem**: I must be able to reorder and remove element from the right area (i.e. the `program` array). I tried multiple solutions, none of them work. Ideally, an element is removed when it is dropped outside of the drop area (i.e. the right column). For now, I simply use a button

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="remove(ctrl.program, $index)"> remove </button>

$scope.remove = function(array, index){
   array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

But it throws

```
Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'
```

Any idea how to perform a remove smoothly ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone gets the same problem, here is the answer.

From this [issue](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/issues/120),

> inserting the script jquery.ui.js after angular.js cause the issue in 1.3 but not 1.2. Specially if the drag or drop directive is used with ngRepeat. On removing the element by $animate.leave , the drag or drop plugin get destroyed by the 'remove' event before the $destroy event.

I inserted `jquery.ui.min.js` ***before*** all the angular scripts and it works perfectly.